# Unable to send mail with attachment using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send a mail with attachment, but failed repeatedly. However without attachment able to send mail. Below is my function.

```
public function sendmail($jid,$eid)
        {           
            $empdata = $this->search_m->eid($eid);
            $user = $this->session->userdata('userid');
            $jsdata = $this->search_m->jid($user);

            foreach($empdata->result() as $rows)
            {
                $empmail = $rows->email;                
            }


            foreach($jsdata->result() as $row)
            {
                $jsres = $row->resume;          
            }


             $file = "uploads/".$jsres;



            $this->load->library('email');
            //$this->email->clear();
            $config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE; 

            $config['protocol'] = 'mail';
            $config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';     
            $config['smtp_port']=587;
            $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_user'] = 'mail@gmail.com';
            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
            $config['validate'] = TRUE;
            $this->email->initialize($config);          

            $this->email->from( 'hr@virtu.com','Gowtham');
            $this->email->to('gorodda@gmail.com');          
            $this->email->subject('Testing Email');
            $this->email->message('I applied to ur job');
            $this->email->attach($file);
            $this->email->send();

            if(!$this->email->send())
                {
                    echo " mail not send";

                }


            }
```

Where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The `$file` would be the **full path** of the uploaded file like

```
$file = site_url()."uploads/".$jsres;
```

Better after uploading the file which you want to send through file ,get the full path of the file from uploaded data and give as `$file`.

Comment: I tried that, even then getting error like this.  
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: Subject

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 982

Comment: just do this echo $this->email->print_debugger(); and tell us what you got

Comment: Added print _debugger. but the output shows nothing. file name is correct and path name too , i checked in uploads folder and file name too.

Comment: No just echo the file name with full path and paste that at your browser.

Comment: I got this error. Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.

User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Mon, 18 Nov 2013 03:57:56 -0700
From: "Gowtham" <hr@virtutechsolutions.com>
Return-Path: <hr@virtutechsolutions.com>
Reply-To: "hr@virtutechsolutions.com" <hr@virtutechsolutions.com>
X-Sender: hr@virtutechsolutions.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5289f2b4396af@virtutechsolutions.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="B_ATC_5289f2b43974f"
=?iso-8859-1?Q?Test_Email?=

Comment: able to send mail without attachment. PHP mail() not working when i tried to send mail with attachment.

Comment: finally got it. just changed my mail protocolo to sendmail and its working. Thank u for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following..

```
 $path = set_realpath('uploads/');
 $this->email->attach($path . $jsres);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, mail sent but without attachment.:(

Answer (score 0):

You can add complete link by using:

```html
$file=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/".$jsres;
```

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will get your localhost address like:

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/mail
```